# “McAfee Antivirus Detects C Executable as Virus (False Positive)

Tags: c, mingw, antivirus, false-positive, virus-scanning

[My VSCode window with the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZozeT.jpg)
I'm encountering a false positive detection by McAfee's antivirus for my C program's executable. When I compile my code using MinGW, McAfee flags it as a virus.

- I've tried excluding the build directory from scanning, but the issue persists.
- Scanning with other antivirus tools (e.g., Malwarebytes) doesn't detect any issues.
- I've also checked the executable on VirusTotal, and some engines detect it as unsafe.
  Any suggestions on how to resolve this without compromising security?
  I attached the screenshot of the code in VSCode with the terminal.

I'm encountering a false positive detection by McAfee's antivirus for my C program's executable. When I compile my code using MinGW, McAfee flags it as a virus.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. **Exclusion from Scanning**:

   - I excluded the build directory from scanning in McAfee settings, but the issue persists.
   - The antivirus didn't identifies the compiled executable as a threat but it's affecting my productivity as after recompiling the files for testing this issue persists and as a learner this causes me to slow my learning speed.
2. **Scanning with Other Antivirus Tools**:

   - I ran a scan using other antivirus tools (e.g., Malwarebytes), and they didn't detect any issues.
   - This suggests that the detection might be a false positive specific to McAfee.
3. **VirusTotal Check**:

   - I uploaded the executable to VirusTotal, and 17 security vendors and no sandboxes flagged this file as malicious.
   - However, most engines did not detect any problems.

I'd like to find a solution that doesn't compromise security while allowing me to run my program seamlessly. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue or further troubleshoot it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: During devepopment exclude your dev directories from scanning and checking

Comment: @Cow: That is not a solution for programmers dealing with McAfee interfering with development on their own systems.

Comment: Is VSCode putting the executable somewhere other than the directory you excluded from McAfee?

Comment: @Cow he is **not publishing** the program only learning C. He needs to to disable checks in some directories

Comment: "I'd like to find a solution that doesn't compromise security" Simply don't download fishy programs from the internet or open mail attachments from random strangers. If you could resist the urge of doing any of that, you don't need a so-called "anti-virus" program lagging up your computer for nothing and preventing you from using it.